# Error: PrettyPrinter is outside the scope of function

Tags: python, csv

this code opens a CSV, reads it and print the first row after the 'header' row. I'm using pprint to have the output of a dictionary. But, my code is not printing anything even with print(). Where am i going wrong?

```
import csv

from datetime import datetime
from pprint import PrettyPrinter 

def print_first_point(filename):
"""
This function prints and returns the first data point (second row) from
a csv file that includes a header row.
"""
# print city name for reference
city = filename.split('-')[0].split('/')[-1]
print('\nCity: {}'.format(city))

with open(filename, 'r') as f_in:
     trip_reader = csv.DictReader(f_in)

    def first_trip (trip_reader):
        reader = csv.DictReader (trip_reader)
        first = next (reader)
        return first

    pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
    pp.pprint(first_trip)
```

Comment: So you have a function in a function you're not calling, because? Can't all of that just be `pp.pprint(next(trip_reader))` inside your `with` statement?

Comment: Sorry, ignore the first function. That part is working. I should'nt have included it.

Comment: And putting `pp.pprint(next(trip_reader))` immediately after you declare `trip_reader` doesn't work?

Comment: It worked. Thanks a bunch. But, if I had to include this part in a function, where was I going wrong?

Comment: Why would you want that part in a function? It's in a function called `print_first_trip` - why have a function *inside that one* called `first_trip`... That given your use case is unnecessarily over complicating things

Comment: Cool. That makes sense.